# javascript : dictionary of functions with "constant" integer as keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary, constants, function-pointers

The following code is working fine:

```
function a() { console.log("a"); };
function b() { console.log("b"); };

var F = {1:a,2:b};

F[1](); // log "a"
F[2](); // log "b"
```

but this one does not:

```
function a() { console.log("a"); };
function b() { console.log("b"); };

var A = 1;
var B = 2;
var F = {A:a,B:b};

F[A](); // log "TypeError : F[A] is not a function"
```

The idea is that A and B would be constant integer, used just for the sake of code readability. I know there are no "const" in javascript, but you get the idea.

What would be the clean way to get something like this work ? (I do not care that much if A and B are effectively constant or not at the end, just having them upper case indicates my future me not to change their value).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi Yep. Hope my example is more readable, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `A` and `B` as identifiers in the JavaScript object you're creating, they aren't referencing the variables you've declared.

Instead you'll have to add them to the JavaScript object like so:

```
function a() { console.log("a"); };
function b() { console.log("b"); };

var A = 1;
var B = 2;
var F = {};
F[A] = a;
F[B] = b;

F[A]();
```

Comment: I am quite confused, thought my code and your code was totally equivalent ... My first batch of code in JavaScript comes with a lots of surprises

Answer (score 15):

In ES6, use computed property names:

```
{ [A]: a }
```

Comment: That has to be the shortest usable answer I ever read here :-)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names

Answer (score 2):

Within an object literal, all the "keys" are interpreted as strings, with or without quotes. So your key is `"A"`, not `1`. Your example is equivalent to `var F = { "A": a, "B": b }`.

Unfortunately, you simply cannot use a variable for a key within an object literal.

The only way to set a variable  key is to use bracket notation:

```
F[A] = a;
```